# Qt - separate string with regular expressions

Tags: regex, qt

is it possible to separate the following string

```
displayName=Exposure Time [µs] unit=ms type=int min=10 max=1000 increment=50
```

with Qt's String::split() method using regular expressions? The result must be:

- displayName=Exposure Time [µs]
- unit=ms
- type=int
- min=10
- max=1000
- increment=50

I know it's not kind but if one could provide me with a solution you'd make my day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you want to use regular expressions? Provide more examples of possible entries since the entry that samples can be interpreted in multiple ways

Comment: What is your separation criterion? The separation at least for me has no logic so it will be difficult to help if you do not give more information.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. I hope this will help you better: So I have a string in the form of key=value key=value and so forth. key is at least one character or a string that might can start with a digit. Except for { and } each symbol should be allowed in either the key's name or the value's name. In the case above whitespace in either of these names should be ok, too. So the generic case is a sequence of key=value pairs with the above mentioned restrictions. Does this help you better? I do not have that much examples yet.

Comment: A key name must of course not contain whitespaces but a value name can

Comment: It's funny to see the different approach, @rkta's solution works fine (if you can rely on the ']' when you have spaces). I had this regex in mind instead : https://regex101.com/r/ZoYAVE/2 but it also captures the space-separator (you can either trim or retrieve the group-capture instead of the match).

Comment: Thank you. Using your regex this way str.split(QRegularExpression("(\w+=[^=]+)(\s|$)"); I get the complete string as above but not a list of strings...

Comment: Regex is evil, dont't ever use it

Comment: Does this *need* to be accomplished using only `Qt` + the standard library?  Or would a `boost` based solution be acceptable?

Comment: In general I do not need to use regex. I just thought it'd be a good idea. Unfortunately I'm restricted to Qt and STL.

Comment: Yes that's it :) Thank you and thanks to everybody

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
s.split(QRegularExpression("\\s+(?=\\w+=)"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XLXYs5/1) (note that `QRegularExpression` uses the PCRE flavor).

**Pattern details**

- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars
- `(?=\w+=)` - a positive lookahead that requires 1 or more word chars (letters, digits or `_` matched with `\w+`) followed with a `=` symbol immediately to the right of the current location.